# blktrace output & block sizes in linux block layer

Tags: linux

I have been using blktrace/blkparse recently and have a couple of questions and would appreciate if somebody can help me out:

1) The number of blocks value in blkparse output is represented in sectors (512 bytes). Is this correct? Is this still applicable in SSDs which don't have 512 bytes sectors?

2) This number of blocks value doesn't go above 2048 (1MB) even if i run a workload which submits data bigger then 1MB blocks (using libaio). Is there a limit on block size that can be submitted to Linux block layer and if the block layer automatically breaks larger blocks into smaller ones? Could somebody point me to kernel codepath where this is done?

Thanks very much in advance.

Terko

Answer (score 1):

Blktrace gets its data from the Linux kernel which considers sectors to be [512 bytes long](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/types.h?v=3.10#L124). So I think that, regardless of the device physical sector size, blktrace displays offsets and sizes in 512-bytes sectors.

You can make a test with dd to verify what happens and record disk accesses with btrace. For instance,

```
dd if=/dev/something of=/dev/null bs=512 count=1 skip=512
```

For your second question, a lot is happening in the block layer: I/O requests are buffered, merged, scheduled. So don't be surprised if the kernel make disk accesses with a different block size than the one specified in your application.